# Sonata password without User entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I've done some research but I can't find a way to set up a password (or login/password) for my admin dashboard without having an Entity User. I'm looking for something like a password in the parameters file or something like that. Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you looked at the in memory user provider? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a User Entity but luckily this is standard available in the Symfony framework. You also need a way to authenticate a user. You could think about a php login-form or a HTTP basic authentication form. You can add users directly in security.yml under the providers section. And do not forget to restrict access to the /admin routes. You can easily follow [this document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

The most simple setup for app/config/security.yml is this:

```
security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: kitten
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now you are able to go to the **/admin** route and then you have to login with user: **admin** and password: **kitten**

Comment: Very nice, that's what I was looking for.